# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n-x^{-n}}{x^n+x^{-n}}$ when $0\lt x \lt 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n-x^{-n}}{x^n+x^{-n}}$ when $0\lt x \lt 1$?

I tried this in two different ways, and I'm getting two different answers.

**Method 1:**

I rewrote the fraction as $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^{2n}+1}$$

Since $x$ lies between $0$ and $1$, $x^{2n} =0$ when $n \to \infty$.

So the limit turns out to be $-1$.

**Method 2:**

Again, starting with
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^{2n}+1}$$

This time I go without taking the constraint on $x$ in consideration. We'll first evaluate the limit for any $x$, then use the constraint that $0\lt x\lt 1$ to simplify the limit obtained further.

Using the L'Hopital Rule we get,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2x^{2n}\log x}{2x^{2n}\log x}$$

This gives the limit to be $1$.

Why do I get two different answers? Which one is correct?

The only problem I see with method 2 is that I can't prove that the fraction is always an $\frac \infty \infty$ or $\frac 00$ type of limit for an arbitrary $x$. So maybe the function gives different values for $x\gt 1$ and $x\lt 1$.

Comment: As you mentioned the given fraction is not "good" for using L'Hopital Rule, so using L'Hopital Rule isn't allowed there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer (and method) is the first one, of course.
In the second case you cannot use L'Hopital Rule: it is NOT an indeterminate form $0/0$. It is a very simple form (-1)/1.

Comment: Say the constraint on $x$ was not given. How would you evaluate the limit then? My guess is that it will be kinda like a composite function. Different values for $x\lt 1$ and $x\gt 1$. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\frac{x^n-x^{-n}}{x^n+x^{-n}}=\tanh (n\log x)$$
For $n>0$, $x\in (0,1)$, $\log x\in (-\infty, 0)$ and then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n-x^{-n}}{x^n+x^{-n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\tanh (n\log x)=-1$$